# fullpage.js wont scroll smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js

I am using wordpress and astra theme with elementor.

I am trying to do a simple website using fullpage.js. I really have no clue about coding and have done the best I can by watching some videos and reading the documentation for fullpage.js.

I just want the slides to scroll smoothly and display properly. Currently everytime I want to scroll it wiggles before scrolling and does when it scrolls it does not properly fit the sections.

Ive read the documentation and tried diffefrent settings but it just does not seem to fix my problem.

This is what i currently have.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //options here
        scrollingSpeed: 700,
        autoScrollin: true,
        navigation: true,
        slidesNavigation: true, 
        css3: true,
        fitToSection: true,
        fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
        scrollBar: true     
    });
    //methods
    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
});
```

I just want the page to scroll smoothly when i use either trackpad or touch.

Comment: It is impossible to help you without an isolated reproduction or more info.

Comment: Alvaro, thanks for your response. I managed to solve the issue by trying a mix of settings. What was causing the wiggle effect when scrolling was sscrollBar: true. Once i set it to false it scrolled smoothly but my backgrounds dissapeared. So I had to set Css3: False and my backgrounds work but now I have Css3 dissabled.

Comment: That might be because you are using fixed positioned backgrounds. Otherwise backgrounds work as expected with the default `css3:true` as can be seen in this [backgrounds demo page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/backgrounds.html).